# how to find the blue dots in the red strips using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am working on a problem and want to find the location and size of the blue dots embedded in the red stripes in the middle, but the problem is that there are many other red regions also in the image but I want only the red stripe in the middle and find the blue dots in that(the location or thickness of the red stripe is not fixed)

[image]

Comment: Can you actually show us what region you're looking at?  "Blue dots in red strips" is really ambiguous - I see a lot of them.

Comment: @rayryeng ya I understand what you are trying to say but the problem is that this problem has a certain level of ambiguity with it, what I want is that if you see below the number 20 then you will find a red and yellowish stripe, there are many blue dots embedded in it, so I want to find them.

Comment: That criteria alone is ambiguous in of itself.  There are many areas in your image that contain this characteristic.

Comment: yup exactly that is the challenge that I want to find just the red and yellowish stripe and then find the blue dots in it.

Comment: Good luck with that!

Comment: Maybe you could add a **second** image with circles around the things you want to find...